# How can I assign bloginfo path or thumbnail path to a variable and call it in markup?

Tags: post-thumbnails, variables

In my head this sound right. I check if the post has a thumbnail. If it has, I assign the post thumbnail to a variable that I call as the source for my background image. If the post does not have a thumbnail, I assign a placeholder image as the background.

However, I'm having some issues :/

The code block below breaks my site, and if I change the `else` statement to `$large_image_url = bloginfo('template_directory')?>/library/images/default-header-image.jpg<?php;` it actually echoes out the variable as a line of text instead of saving it in the variable.

```
<?php 
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    $large_image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), '' );
} else {
    $large_image_url = bloginfo('template_directory')'/library/images/default-header-image.jpg';
} ?>

<section class="header-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $large_image_url[0] ?>');">
</section>
```

Can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bloginfo()` function outputs immediately. since you're storing to a $variable you'll want to use `get_bloginfo()` instead. also, you're missing a concatenation.

```
$large_image_url = get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/library/images/default-header-image.jpg';
```

Comment: Thank you @karpstrucking! That was indeed the issue :) I ran into another issue though, I'm echoing `$large_image_url[0]` and that doesn't seem to work for the bloginfo. I'm thinking it's becuase the thumbnail is an object and originally i'm extracting the url from that image.. Can I somehow make that spesific to the thumbnail?

Comment: try adding `$large_image_url = array( $large_image_url );` to the `else {}` (after the `get_bloginfo` line). this should convert it to an array with the url as the first key